# How to scroll ag-grid horizontally on search of column name

Tags: javascript, angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular11

I am using ag-grid-angular. I have one autocomplete/search box, If I enter any characters in search box I need to match those characters with grid's column name and need to highlight/show column as selected. if that column is not visible on the viewport because of large grid and columns then I need to scroll the grid horizontally till that column.

I am using angular 11 and ag-grid. I tried it with gridApi but there no such a horizontal scroll functionality available in ag-grid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should use the `ensureColumnVisible` method in the GridAPI.

See more info here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-scrolling-ensureColumnVisible